# Check if the sum of a column is positive mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I've created a table with multiple accounts Let's say it looks like this

```
No   name   balance 
 1    henk    100
 2    henk    -200
 3    piet    300
 4    piet    -100
```

How can I check if the total balance of Henk is positive

I've come up with this

```
delimiter //

Create trigger Positivebalance after insert on account

for each row

begin

    if sum(new.balance) < 0 THEN

        set @msg = 'Not enough money';
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = @msg;
    end if;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

But this is wrong, any idea?

Comment: If you are testing if you can do a thing then a before trigger is more appropriate, You cannot sum in isolation - and I don't get what you are doing here - if you are inserting a balance then you just check new.balance.- where does summing a column come into it?

Comment: How do *you* define "total balance"?

Comment: Terminology problem:  A "balance" is the _sum_ of all the transactions that have gone before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE
WHEN sum(new.balance) < 0 then 'Not enough money'
else 'More than enough money'
End as [assign an alias]
```

```
No   name   balance      [alias]
 1    henk    100   More than enough Money
 2    henk    -200  Not enough money
 3    piet    300   More than enough Money
 4    piet    -100  Not enough money
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the code to fetch the **henk** account_status.

```
SELECT No
    ,Name
    ,Sum(balance)
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUM(balance) > 0
            THEN 'Enough Money in Account'
        WHEN SUM(balance) < 0
            THEN 'Not Enough Money in Account'
        END AS Account_Status
FROM Your_Table
GROUP BY No,Name

    --You fecth a single record as well I have called in variable --
    --you can call the below code in proc and fecth record as per passed values in parameter--

DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100)
SET @NAME = 'henk'
SELECT No
    ,Name
    ,Sum(balance)
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SUM(balance) > 0
            THEN 'Enough Money in Account'
        WHEN SUM(balance) < 0
            THEN 'Not Enough Money in Account'
        END AS Account_Status
FROM Your_Table
GROUP BY No
    ,Name
WHERE Name = @Name
```